# Query index page to filter results shown in table - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

I am trying to filter the index page of a todo list, I have column `t.datetime "completed_at"` in my tasks table.

Currently my form looks like this,

```
<%= form_with model: @task, method: :GET do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Complete" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :completed, "complete" %>

  <%= f.label "Incompleted" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :completed, "incomplete" %>

  <%= f.label "All tasks" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :completed, "all_tasks" %>

  <%= f.submit "Filter" %>
<% end %>
```

and my controller

```
  def index
    if params[:completed] == "complete"
      @tasks = Task.where(completed_at: !nil)
    elsif params[:completed] == "incomplete"
      @tasks = Task.where(completed_at: nil)
    else
      @tasks = Task.all
    end
  end
```

I am trying to use `completed_at` equalling nil to be an incomplete task, and complete tasks will be `!nil` as a datetime will be stored when checked as complete. If anyone could point me in the right direction or give an example of how to get this working I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

rails - 6
ruby - 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By negating `nil` you'll get `true`, so that won't filter tasks with not `nil` `completed_at` rows, but tasks with `completed_at` as true.

You could assign `@tasks` to `Task.all`, and then depending on the value of `params[:completed]` modify it:

```
def index
  completed = params[:completed]
  @tasks = Task.all
  @tasks = Task.where.not(completed_at: nil) if completed == 'complete'
  @tasks = Task.where(completed_at: nil) if completed == 'incomplete'
end
```

`where.not` does the trick to perform an `IS NOT NULL` query.

Or if you want to be more object-oriented;

```
class Tasks
  def initialize(completed)
    @completed = completed
  end

  def complete_filter
    return Task.where.not(completed_at: nil) if complete?
    return Task.where(completed_at: nil) incomplete?

    Task.all
  end

  private

  attr_reader :completed

  def complete?
    completed == 'complete'
  end

  def incomplete?
    completed == 'incomplete'
  end
end

def index
  @tasks = Tasks.new(params[:completed]).complete_filter
end
```

Comment: The first example was correct and helped me, when I have more time I may try your second suggestion also. Thanks!